# Javascript array elements not being displayed in div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I've created a program that reads JSON data for a concert event. The JSON file has one object named global which has the band name and the venue. There is also a tickets object containing all of the available tickets for the concert, from which I am getting the ticket price, the section, and the row (for the seats). When using `console.log()` to print out specific attributes from the parsed JSON, I am getting the correct output. I have a function that reads the parsedJSON object into different arrays (one for ticketInfo and another for the general event info). In another function, I use some jquery functionality to add the contents of the arrays to a div on the page, but nothing is being displayed when the page loads. I'm new to jquery so I probably have some simple mistake which is causing the problem but can anyone tell where the code is wrong?

The relevant code is below:

```
<div id="container"> Container div  </div>

<script>
var concertData = {};
var eventInfo = {};
var ticketInfo = {};

function makeInvite() {
    var metaInfo = concertData['global'][0];
    eventInfo['venue'] = metaInfo['mapTitle'];
    eventInfo['band'] = metaInfo['productionName'];

    for (var i = 0; i < concertData['ticket'].length; i++) {
        var ii = concertData['ticket'][i];
        var temp = {
        'section': ii['l'],
        'price': ii['p'],
        'row': ii['r'],
    };
    ticketInfo[i] = temp;
    }
}

function buildQuestionToScreen() {
    var inviteObj = $('<div style="margin:20px"></div>');
    inviteObj.append(
    '<div>Invite a friend to see ' + eventInfo['band'] + '?</div>'
    );
    var $div = $("<div></div>");
    var $divLine = $("<tr></tr>");
    console.log(eventInfo['band']);
    var $table = $("<table></table>");
    for (var j = 0; j < ticketInfo.length; j++) {
        var $line = $("<tr></tr>");
        $line.append($("<td></td>").html(ticketInfo[j][0]));
        $line.append($("<td></td>").html(ticketInfo[j][1]));
        $line.append($("<td></td>").html(ticketInfo[j][2]));
        $table.append($line);
    }
    //$table.appendTo(document.body);
    $inviteObj.appendTo($("#container"));
    $table.appendTo($("#container"));
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'concertInfo.json',
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        concertData = data;
        makeInvite();
        buildQuestionToScreen();
        $(data.tickets).each(function(index, value){
                console.log(value.p);
        });
    }
})

</script>
```

#### EDIT-Here is the relevant part of the JSON file being read from:

```
{

   "global": [

      {

         "dte": "1",

         "atp": "116.33",

         "lp": "74.00",

         "hp": "183.00",

         "listingCount": "3",

         "hq": "8",

         "vpcr": "exp0818",

         "mapTitle": "Terminal 5",

         "productionId": "1817728",

         "productionName": "Glass Animals",

         "eventId": "35873",

         "venueId": "5351",

         "zoned": "0",

         "staticMapUrl": "http://d2o50i5c2dr30a.cloudfront.net/e19c6a1e-f606-46df-82c2-230544edc2a5.jpg",

      }

   ],

   "tickets": [

      {
         "s": "GENERAL A..",

         "r": "GA6",

         "q": "1",

         "p": "74.00",

         "i": "VB916157659",

         "l": "GENERAL ADMISSION",
      },
```

Comment: Where are you calling `makeInvite` and `buildQuestionToScreen`?

Comment: You need to make sure that the `makeInvite` and `buildQuestionToScreen` are called after the ajax request is completed

Comment: Can you post your JSON as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: where are `['l']` , `['p']` and `['r']` indexes comming from?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: and where are you calling those methods which actually `add the contents of the arrays to a div on the page`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I tried calling ```buildQuestionToScreen()``` and ```makeInvite()``` after the ajax call but it's still not working

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: You should call them inside your success method

Comment: @SandeepNayak Ok, just tried that but it didn't work...Does the code look correct though? I think that the problem maybe with how the jQuery is used in the ```buildQuestionToScreen()``` function, but if the code looks right than, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that you are assigning the `concertData` variable the returned string `data` and not the parsed JSON in your AJAX call.

Try changing the line following line

```
concertData = data;
```

to

```
concertData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Alternatively, instead of the above tweak, you can specify a `dataType` property (set to `'json'`) to your AJAX call. In this case, the "json" evaluates the response of your request as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'concertInfo.json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
       concertData = data;
       makeInvite();
       buildQuestionToScreen();
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, the error seems to have gone away now. But I'm getting the error that $inviteObj is undefined when in the buildQuestionToScreen() function when its clearly defined there. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: You're welcome... What is the log in console when you reach `$inviteObj`?

Comment: I just left out the "$" before the append to ```$inviteobj``` so it was undefined

Comment: I think the variable in the line `$inviteObj.appendTo($("#container"));` should be either as `$(inviteObj)` or simply `inviteObj`.